# Laravel - Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, laravel, poo

Estoy empezando a aprender laravel y cuando intento instalar homestead mediante git, me tira este error:

[image: Imagen de error de laravel/homestead]

Ya tengo varios días sin poder resolverlo, ya intenté entrar al link que me proporciona la consola y no me ha ayudado en nada. Ya hice login con mi cuenta de vagrant por la consola pero tampoco me deja ingresar a eso.
Agradecería mucho su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate de que tienes la versión más actual de vagrant:

`vagrant box update`

Sino, intenta con esto:

`vagrant box add laravel/homestead https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead`

Comment: Cuando uso 'vagrant box update' me pone este mensaje:
==> default: Box 'laravel/homestead' not installed, can't check for udates.

¿Qué hago?